# How to change the variables in $\frac{1}{(z+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left( \frac{1}{z+1}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We know that 
$$\frac{1}{(z+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left( \frac{1}{z+1}\right).$$

If we put $z=e^t$ how can we change the variables above equation?

I know that $z\frac{d}{dz}=\frac{d}{dt}$. So how can we write $\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left( \frac{1}{z+1}\right)$?

Is $z^n \frac{d^n}{dz^n}=\frac{d^n}{dt^n}$?

Comment: $$z^n\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\ne \frac{d^n}{dt^n}=(z\frac{d}{dz})^n$$

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you. So how to write it to obtain $\frac{1}{(e^t+1)^{n+1}}$? Do we need to use Stirling numbers?

Comment: Yes, in general for a $n$ times differentiable function $f$ we have$$\left(z\frac{d}{dz}\right)^n\{f\}=\sum_{k=1}^n  \begin{Bmatrix} n \\ k \end{Bmatrix}z^k\frac{d^k\,f}{dz^k}$$

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $f(z)$ is $n$ times differentiable, then we have

$$\left(z\frac{d}{dz}\right)^n\{f(z)\}=\sum_{k=1}^n  \begin{Bmatrix} n \\ k \end{Bmatrix}z^k\frac{d^k\,f(z)}{dz^k}$$

where $\begin{Bmatrix} n \\ k \end{Bmatrix}=\frac1{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}\,j^n$ are the [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Definition).

For $f(z)=\frac1{z+1}$, we find

$$\begin{align}
\left(z\frac{d}{dz}\right)^n\left(\frac{1}{1+z}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n  \begin{Bmatrix} n \\ k \end{Bmatrix}z^k\frac{(-1)^k\,k!}{(1+z)^{k+1}}
\end{align}$$

Letting $z=e^t$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^t}\right)&=\frac{1}{1+e^t}\sum_{k=1}^n  \begin{Bmatrix} n \\ k \end{Bmatrix}(-1)^k\,k! \left(\frac{e^t}{1+e^t}\right)^k\\\\
&=\frac1{1+e^t}\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j\binom{k}{j}j^n\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-t}}\right)^k
\end{align}$$

Comment: But from this, we cannot get the formula for $\frac{1}{(e^t+1)^{n+1}}$.

Comment: @SomaWick What do you mean?  We have an explicit formula for the derivative that involves a finite sum with the Stirling coefficients or a double finite sum with the binomial coefficients.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I want to write an explicit formula for $\frac{1}{(e^t+1)^{n+1}}$. That is my whole intention.

Comment: You're welcome.  It was my pleasure.  And now you have an explicit formula for the $n$th derivative of $\frac1{1+e^t}$.

Comment: And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.